# Replace a whole line in a file

Tags: python, file, replace

I have a .txt file containing data like this:

```
0,Rent1,Expense,16/02/2010,1,4000,4000  
0,Car Loan1,Expense,16/02/2010,2,4500,9000  
0,Flat Loan1,Expense,16/02/2010,2,4000,8000  
0,Rent2,Expense,16/02/2010,1,4000,4000  
0,Car Loan2,Expense,16/02/2010,2,4500,9000  
0,Flat Loan2,Expense,16/02/2010,2,4000,8000
```

Now i want to replace the line 4 with the new items like:

0,Loan,Expense,19/02/2010,2,5000,10000

I use the following code:

```
newline='0,Loan,Expense,19/02/2010,2,5000,10000'
lnum=1
for line in fileinput.FileInput("sample.txt",inplace=1):
    if lnum=='4':
        result = newline
        lnum=lnum+1
    else:
        result=line
        lnum=lnum+1
    sys.stdout.write(result)
```

But it shows the in file like:

```
0,Rent1,Expense,16/02/2010,1,4000,4000  
0,Car Loan1,Expense,16/02/2010,2,4500,9000  
0,Flat Loan1,Expense,16/02/2010,2,4000,8000  
0,Loan,Expense,19/02/2010,2,5000,100000,Car Loan2,Expense,16/02/2010,2,4500,9000
0,Flat Loan2,Expense,16/02/2010,2,4000,8000
```

How can I solve this?

Comment: @bp: It's all one question... in 23 parts.

Comment: Ok guy, you asked almost the same question four times in S0. Stop doing that, it's annoying.

Comment: What's more, people already gave you anwsers that match all your needs. Stop asking and get to work.

Comment: Well, each time a different question is asked so that's not really a problem. It would be better, however, if he actually used the checkmarks...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Replace:

```
result = newline #you lose the newline here
```

with:

```
result = newline + '\n' #or '\r\n' depending on your newline format.
```

Answer (score 2):

Put a new line

```
newline='0,Loan,Expense,19/02/2010,2,5000,10000'
lnum=1
for line in fileinput.FileInput("sample.txt",inplace=1):
    if lnum==4:
        result = newline+"\n"
    else:
        result=line
    lnum=lnum+1    
    sys.stdout.write(result)
```

Or you can just declare `newline` variable as

```
newline="0,Loan,Expense,19/02/2010,2,5000,10000\n"
```

Comment: Also, `lnum=='4'` should be `lnum == 4`. Python is strongly typed.

Answer (score 1):

Use **enumerate**: *less code less error posibilities*

```
newline = '0,Loan,Expense,19/02/2010,2,5000,10000\n'
for lnum, line in enumerate(fileinput.FileInput("sample.txt",inplace=1)):
    if lnum == 4:
        line = newline
sys.stdout.write(line)
```

Answer (score 0):

`sys.stdout.write()` does not add a newline. Either append a `\n`, use `print` after, or use `print`'s file syntax:

```
print >>sys.stdout, result
```

... Or since `sys.stdout` is the default:

```
print result
```